# Problem in dynamically creating ASP.NET report viewer web control

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I want to dynamically create an ASP.NET report viewer web control, but got the exception below:

The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form.

Below is my code:

```
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();

    viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = "server url";
    viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "reprot path";

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
    Page page = new Page();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();

    form.Controls.Add(scriptManager);
    form.Controls.Add(viewer);
    page.Controls.Add(form);

    page.DataBind();  //exception here
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following tag to your aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id='scriptManager' runat='server' />
```

Comment: Brian Scott, it is in code hehind c#, not on aspx source view.

Comment: @Pingpong: Yes, but if you add this tag then the scriptmanager will be present as a code behind server object.

Comment: Excellent. States it is required to place inside the FORM-tag, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line inside the form tag on your ASPX Page

and must use **IsPostBack on your page load** to avoid infinite loop